# Add Wordpress plugin error on : Class 'WP_Plugin_Install_List_Table' not found

Tags: wordpress, class, plugins, fatal-error

[check this screen for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYkgG.png)

- Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Plugin_Install_List_Table' not found in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/list-table.php on line 74
- Error: Class 'WP_Plugin_Install_List_Table' not found in /var/www/html/wp-admin/includes/list-table.php on line 74
- When I want to add a plugin by my back-office, this error happens
- When I try to install a plugin manually by FTP, nothing is happening ( I checked the path several times, it's the right one for sure ). Nothing is happening, in my admin plugin, the new plugin is not even displayed.

The list-table.php file is not empty, has the right path and I changed it by a new one from a new wordpress.

So what can I try to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advice